# Joining tables with different number of rows without duplicates

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, union

I have an already complicated SQL statement that creates a table of users who have the rights `CONNECT`, `APPUSER`, or both:

```
(SELECT  b.grantee AS "Username", A.granted_role AS "Connect", b.granted_role AS "APPUSER" FROM 
    (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'CONNECT')  A 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'APPUSER') b 
    ON A.grantee=b.grantee) 
UNION 
(SELECT  A.grantee, A.granted_role, b.granted_role FROM 
    (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'CONNECT')  A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'APPUSER') b 
    ON A.grantee=b.grantee)
```

This produces something like:

```
Username        Connect        APPUSER
---------      ---------      ---------
Sue             CONNECT        APPUSER
Bob             (null)         APPUSER
Joe             CONNECT        (null)
```

**I wish to use the `all_users` table, to also show users who have neither rights.**  The `all_users` table shows every user in the database.

I have tried adding several types of joins to the end of my SQL statement to achieve this.  The closest I got was adding:

```
UNION
(SELECT username, NULL, NULL FROM all_users)
```

This would produce a list where each user is shown twice, but shows users without either right:

```
Username        Connect        APPUSER
---------      ---------      ---------
Amy             (null)         (null)
Sue             CONNECT        APPUSER
Sue             (null)         (null)
Bob             (null)         APPUSER
Bob             (null)         (null)
Joe             CONNECT        (null)
Joe             (null)         (null)
```

I tried adding a `where username = a.grantee`, but that won't work with Unions.  If I try replacing `UNION` with any `JOIN`s, like adding:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
SELECT username, NULL, NULL FROM ALL_USERS 
on username = a.grantee;
```

I get the error:

> "SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems way more complicated than necessary.  Here is one approach:

```
select grantee,
       max(case when granted_role = 'CONNECT' then granted_role end) as "connect",
       max(case when granted_role = 'APPUSER' then granted_role end) as "appuser"
from dba_role_privs
group by grantee;
```

If there are users that have no roles at all, then you will need the `all_users` table.

EDIT:

Just use a `left join`:

```
select au.userName,
       max(case when granted_role = 'CONNECT' then granted_role end) as "connect",
       max(case when granted_role = 'APPUSER' then granted_role end) as "appuser"
from all_users au join
     dba_role_privs rp
     on au.userName = rp.grantee
group by au.userName;
```

Comment: Thank you for a simplified approach. I do have users that have no roles at all. Working now with the method you provided to see if I can link the `all_users` table.

Comment: Although the simplified approach works perfectly, I am still failing to find a way to use the `all_users` table to show users with no roles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand the first query. It seems like you're doing something really complex when you could use a PIVOT. However, if it's working right, then you should be able to just do:

```
SELECT username 
FROM ALL_USERS 
WHERE username NOT IN (
(SELECT DISTINCT b.grantee AS "Username", A.granted_role AS "Connect", b.granted_role AS "APPUSER" FROM 
        (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'CONNECT')  A 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'APPUSER') b 
        ON A.grantee=b.grantee) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT  A.grantee, A.granted_role, b.granted_role FROM 
        (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'CONNECT')  A 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT grantee, granted_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE granted_role = 'APPUSER') b 
        ON A.grantee=b.grantee)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it gives the error: "Too many values".

Comment: Hmm, sorry, that usually works in SQL Server, but I just realized you're on Oracle. Try adding a DISTINCT in there. See my latest edit. If that doesn't work, maybe use "NOT EXISTS" instead of "NOT IN"?

Answer (score 1):

use the below query. Let me know if this works. You need to add dp1.granted_role is null and dp2.granted_role is null at the where clause.

```
select     au.username,
           dp1.granted_role,
           dp2.granted_role

    from all_users au 
    left join dba_role_privs drp1 on drp1.grantee=au.username and drp1.granted_role='CONNECT'
    left join dba_role_privs drp2 on drp2.grantee=au.username and drp2.granted_role='APPUSER'
```

Comment: Hello and thank you.  The query you provided gives the error "table or view does not exist".